# Google Analytics Script not Firing in IE. No other elements on the page to corrupt the script

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-analytics, doctype

I have a page with nothing but the Google Analytics code on it. It works in all browser except for IE and I've even been able to get other scripts to fire on this page; however, the GA script will not fire. I'm using Fiddler to verify that it is working.

What's missing? This is frustrating.

IE9 64-Bit

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-947358-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the developer tools in IE to check if the ga.js is loaded properly?

Comment: Are you loading the page via `http` or `file`?

Comment: I've used both the IE dev tools & Fiddler to try and verify that it's loading properly. The script doesn't execute when the page is loaded via both `http` and `file`

Answer (score 0):

IE9 has a tracking protection feature -- 
If google-analytics.com is in the tracking protection list it may keep ga.js from loading.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on this one. I checked and it appears to be an opt-in feature, so I don't think it's the root cause here.